# adb: error: Read-only file system when trying to push hosts file

Tags: android, adb, hosts

I try to push updated hosts file into the android device which I create with Android Studio.

I follow these steps:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices
~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 remount
~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 pull /system/etc/hosts ~/Desktop/
~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 push ~/Desktop/hosts /system/etc/hosts
```

After the last command, I get this error:
"adb: error: failed to copy '~/Desktop/hosts' to '/system/etc/hosts': Read-only file system"

About 2 months ago, I tried the same steps and I didn't get any errors. It worked correctly.

What more should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved.
I removed the virtual device and set up a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Creating new virtual devices everytime is not the most practical option. As of March 2018, you can follow these steps and you should be able to modify the android hosts file:

Open terminal then:

```
android list avd
```

Now copy the `Name` of the AVD you want to use. For example, my AVD's name is `Nexus_4_API_19`.

```
emulator -avd Nexus_4_API_19 -writable-system
```

Open a new terminal window and:

```
adb remount
adb pull /system/etc/hosts /Users/{username}/Documents/
```

Edit the hosts file adding an entry pointing to your host computer. Example:

```
192.168.0.31            mywebsite.com
```

Then

```
adb push /Users/{username}/Documents/hosts /system/etc
```